# core-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT-api.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, gradle, build.gradle

Android app build in Jenkins show follow.Jenkins run on container inside with Linux :

```
> Task :app:hiltAggregateDepsDebug
WARNING: [Processor] Library '/root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/866299741cb63fc82191047ff210aa2e/transformed/core-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT-api.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
 Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/core/R$styleable'
 Example of support library reference: 'android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Default'
```

I don't know why show this message?